# Retrieve a domain name based on an IP Address?

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, ip, tcpip, nslookup

I'm reviewing some apache logs, specifically with respect to downloaded files.  I'm interested in knowing, if possible, which domain is responsible for the download, given an IP address.

I've given nslookup a try and it seems to (mostly) get the job done but it returns all sorts of extraneous information.  Ideally, I pass in an IP and receive a domain back.

Before I write a shell script to parse the output of nslookup to capture the domain, I'd like to know if this is the best way of approaching this problem, or if there is a more tried-and-true method of doing this.

Specifically, I'd like to know if an address resolves to an amazonaws.com domain.  I understand that this might be difficult because EC2 machines are dynamically created and destroyed - I'd like to know if the IP addresses for AWS/EC2/EMR machines fit any sort of addressing pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the IP ranges owned by Amazon for EC2.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/ann.jspa?annID=857

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  How good is Amazon at keeping this information up-to-date?

Comment: It is from a sticky in their forums.  The 50.16/16 block is fairly new, so I am guessing at least weekly

Answer (score 2):

```
$ host 173.242.113.231
```

This will only work if there is a PTR record for that domain though.

Comment: In that case, to only retrieve the domain, would it be as simple as "host x.x.y.y | awk '{print $5}'" ?  Are there any exceptions or other cases?

Comment: Yep, that's right. Trim the trailing '.' though.

Comment: or dig -x x.y.z.a and you'll get the reverse dns lookup for it.  Not infallible, relies on the PTR existing.

Comment: You can also whois and IP address, and get some info on who owns it, what the AS is, etc. Quite interesting.  TeamCymru (http://www.team-cymru.org/Services/ip-to-asn.html) have a nice tool for doing this a bit more programatically.

Comment: Tom O'Connor has a much better way than using `host'.

Answer (score 1):

Not all IPs will have PTR records. If you're looking for what "entity" owns the IP you may also want to check Whois. You're not going to reach 100% on this because of NAT, Virtualization, Hosting, ISPs etc... I may access your site from example.com, but the IP used will just resolve to host.genericISP.com